# How to dynamically create query, with params from an array?

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

Input - ["eq,"comp",....""] (can be 1 to n number of values)

Based on the number of input values in the array, number of conditions should be built. If there are 3 params, then three AND conditions, etc.

Output - "SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Eq = true AND comp = true"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
%dw 2.0
output text
---
"SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE " ++ (payload map ($ ++ " = true") joinBy " AND ")
```